# The people vs people

Tags: articles

The most important assets are people  vs are **the** people

Could you help, please

Comment: I was considering flagging as a duplicate @AndrewLeach, but "the people" has an idiomatic meaning that hasn't to my knowledge been covered by a previous question so I felt it warranted an answer on that basis given the example used.

Comment: @JohnClifford That's why I delayed marking as a duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

As with most things you apply the definite article to, the difference is specificity. If you say

> The most important assets are people

You're just saying that what's important is people in general, but no specific group or subset of them.

> The most important assets are the people

Would be referring to the population of a particular place (as per the idiom). It could also be referring to a specific subset of people already referred to, but this is unlikely as usually if we refer to a specific group of people we give them a more specific name, like "the workers", "the French", "the employees" etc.